# Vue3: How to two way bind the currentTime of <video> Element with pinia

Tags: vue.js, vuejs3, pinia

I’m looking for a way to two-way bind the `currentTime` of a video to a variable in my pinia store. I’m trying to implement a bookmark functionality, however with my current implementation, the `store.currentVideoTime` never updates to the actual video position, but only stays at whatever value I last put in myself.

```
<video
    controls
    crossorigin
    playsinline
    autoplay
    :currentTime="store.currentVideoTime"
    :key="store.currentVideoLink"
>
    <source :src="store.currentVideoLink" type="video/mp4" />
</video>
```

...

```
setup() {
        const store = useVideosStore()

        return {
            store,
        }
    }
```

I also tried using `:currentTime.prop` instead, with the same result

Comment: Did you check on the subject? It's not a good idea to do two-way binding for it at all https://github.com/vuejs/vue/issues/10542 . And two-way binding for a store should call actions on write